# DB2 reference resultset without requiring subquery

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

Is there a way using DB2 sql to reference the result set of a query, such as to do a SUM on a column, without doing a subquery (where you'd have to ensure that the subquery always matches 100% with the main query)?

For example, something as simple as wanting to acquire a percentage value of each row in a numeric column, using the combined sum of the output?

For example:

```
SELECT
  NET,
  NET / (HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO REFERENCE THE NET COLUMN FROM THE RESULT) 
  AS NETPERCENTAGE
FROM
  MYTABLE
WHERE
  [MY CLAUSES]
```

Comment: Have you checked out the OLAP functions?

Comment: Yup, thanks, I learned that I can just use SUM(NET) OVER(). Thanks!

Comment: If you like my hint please upvote